# angular-nvd3 : forcing date range on X Axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using angular-nvd3-directives (http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/line.chart.html)

The HTML in template is:

```
<nvd3-line-chart  
  data="graphData"  
  id="exampleId"  
  interactive="true"  
  tooltips="true"  
  showXAxis="true"  
  showYAxis="true"  
  yAxisLabel="Riders"       
  margin="{left:75,top:20,bottom:45,right:30}"  
  xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormat"  
  xAxisTickValues="xAxisTicks"  
  x="xFunction()"  
  color="routeColour()"  
  legendColor="routeColour()"  
  showLegend="true"  
  >  
  <svg></svg>  
</nvd3-line-chart>
```

The js in the controller(legend function omitted here but that works):

```
  $scope.graphData =[{  
    key: "R1",  
    values: [["2014-1-1", 200], ["2014-1-2", 250]]  
  },  
  {  
    key: "R2",  
    values: [["2014-1-1", 300], ["2014-1-2", 350]]  
  }]  

  $scope.xAxisTicks = function(){  
    return [new Date('2013-12-31'), new Date('2014-1-1'), new Date('2014-1-2'), new Date('2014-1-3')];  
  }  

  $scope.xAxisTickFormat = function(d){  
    if((typeof d)=="number")  
      return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(moment.unix((d/1000)).toDate());  
    else  
      return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(d);  
  }  

  $scope.xFunction = function(){  
    return function(d){  
      return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse(d[0]);           
    };  
  }
```

The graph displays properly, except that the x-axis does not spread over the range of 31 Dec - 3 Jan as intended. X-axis starts at 1 Jan and ends at 2 Jan. I have tried this using forcex as well, but did not work. Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.xDomain([minValue,maxValue])` ?

Comment: yes. I have tried with xaxisdomain (attribute name in angular-nvd3) and forcex. It should work either with xAxisTickValues or forcex, I have used it before for non-date domain. Not working in the current case.

Comment: I got it done with a workaround and forcex. Used integers as x-axis points and displayed them as date strings via xaxistickfomart. So again, worked for integers, not for dates. I will post it an answer unless someone comes up with something better.

Comment: @trappedIntoCode I'm having your same problem, although I can't get it working even with integers like you said (in my case they are already unix timestamp converted with xaxistickfomart). Could you please post your solution?

Comment: Replace attributes as xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormat()"  
  xAxisTickValues="xAxisTicks()"